# Problem stacking ADS1292r ECG shield and Wifi shield on Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi

I want to use ADS1292r ECG shield with Arduino Uno (Seeeduino V4.2) and store the data in an SD card through an Wifi shield. But the ADS1292r shield uses Digital pin 4 for "RESET" purposes, while the same pin is the "SD card select" pin for the WiFi shield. So if I stack all 3 of them, the SD card can't be initialized. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: At the very least for questions like this provide hot-links for the part's circuit diagrams. Most engineers who answer questions here would just design what is needed and so mentioning shields is probably not helpful without links.

Comment: https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-wifi-shield

Comment: I am using below 3 parts: https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-wifi-shield, http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Seeeduino_v4.2/ https://github.com/Protocentral/ADS1292rShield_Breakout

Answer (score 1):

As a generic answer to these sorts of problems (same pin needed by different libraries), I have had success with slightly bending the pin of the top shield to the side to that it doesn't make direct contact with the board underneath (ie doesn't plug into the header socket).

Assuming the shields are all stackable, you can run a jumper wire from the top of the pin to any other pin which is permitted by the configuration. If not, you may have to solder a wire.

In your example, put the WiFi shield on top with its D4 pin bent to the side (with ECG shield between Uno and WiFi shield) , and run a jumper between the **tops** of D3 and D4 (ie on the WiFi Shield). Thus the SD Card select would now be set to D3 instead of D4, and no other connection is made to D4 on the WiFi shield.

I can't verify that you won't have trouble with other pins (eg it looks like both shields use D7).